# Weird output from console.log(res) NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, response, console.log

While using console.log on the response Obj from createServer, the output prints **ServerResponse** before printing the actual object data. I wonder what is so special about res, which causes this effect ???

```
...
http.createServer((req, res) => {  
// Parsing and Logging endpoint on console.
const URL = url.parse(req.url, true).pathname;
console.log(res);
});
...
```

[image]

Comment: Because it's a [`ServerResponse`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not special. `res` is an object, not a string. That's just how Node.js's `console.log` shows objects. For example:

```
class Example {
    constructor() {
        this.foo = "bar";
    }
}
console.log(new Example);
```

outputs:

```
Example { foo: 'bar' }
```

You're telling it to log a [`ServerResponse`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse) object, so it does, creating output similar to the above, just with a lot more properties.

Comment: Don't mind my lack of knowledge but can you please explain what is the difference between 
class E {};
let a = new E;

and 

let a = {};

as they both have different output

Comment: @VipulBhardwaj The one `a` is an `instanceof E` (it inherits from `E.prototype`) while the other is not.

Comment: @VipulBhardwaj - Adding to Bergi's comment above: The output includes the name of the constructor function associated with the object. In `new E`, the constructor function is `E`. In `{}`, it's `Object`.

Comment: Umm.. I am really confused here, Thank you everyone for helping. I will try to read more about the differences and try to understand the whole picture.